# Can we get details of the user from FirebaseAuth

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have made an app that uses phone number authentication and logs in.
So can we get the mobile number from the firebaseAuth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the FirebaseUser object has a [getPhoneNumber()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseUser#getPhoneNumber()) method.